When marking main activity as `singleTask`, it will destroy other activities when launched from the launcher
When marking the main activity as singleTask, it will destroy other activities when launched from the Launcher. But when launched from Recents, it will just resume the latest opened activity. Why does it work like that? And how can I prevent it.
So to illustrate, (Activity A is marked as singleTask), the behaviour is as follows:
Activity A -> Activity B -> Open app from Launcher -> Activity A
Activity A -> Activity B -> Open app from Recents -> Activity A -> Activity B
I would expect the same stack (A -> B) when opening from the Launcher.
I read a lot of StackOverflow and Reddit posts, but none of them seem to fully apply to my situation and/or correctly explain why it's happening and how to solve it.
This post for example, seems to describe my exact problem. However I don't know how the mentioned solution should work. Because in my reproduction onCreate is never called. Moreover Activity B is destroyed. So even when I would be able to call finish in the onCreate method in Activity A, I would end up finishing the whole app instead of only that instance of Activity A
Reproduction on GitHub: https://github.com/tafelnl/android-single-task-launch-reproduction It's just a simple app with two activities. The MainActivity is marked as singleTask and launches SecondActivity by means of an intent. You can observe that the behaviour is as mentioned above.

Is there any need to specify the launchMode in Activity A? I think not specifying  launchMode to singleTask should solve the issue.

Do not use singleTask launchMode on your MainActivity (ACTION_MAIN & CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) in case of other Activities (e.g. SecondActivity) being destroyed by Android in the same taskAffinity when user tap on the Launcher to bring your app to foreground.
Alternatively, safely, if you do certainly need to do that on purpose to maintain a singleton Activity, you could create a SplashActivity as entry Activity without any UI for good regardless of other diverse launchMode set on the later Activities:
<!-- AndroidManifest -->
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:launchMode="standard">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>


// SplashActivity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}


Your solution with specifying a SplashActivity actually seems to do the trick. Thanks. I've got three questions about this: 1. Does it incur worse performance because of starting the main activity after splash has been created? 2. A custom splash is deprecated as of Android 12, should I worry about that? 3. I have another custom <intent-filter for deeplinking/branch. Can I just leave those in the MainActivity without it causing any problems?

There is no doubt on your first two questions. Just try it for the 3rd one.

The splash implementation is not as deprecated way like you said, just a normal but blank activity. Try it for the 3rd one, I have no idea about that, qaq.

Plus, I think you can put the intent-filter tag on that splash activity and pass data to your MainActivity to handle before do finish().

The thing is that Branch.io requires you to specify launchMode="singleTask" on the Activity that has the intent-filter (https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration#4-configure-app)
Also I'm using Capacitor.js, which requires/strongly recommends the launchMode="singleTask" as well

Please let me know if you have already tried for my solution in your scenario whatever it works or not. Thanks a lot.

It seems to work so far. But it's hard to cover every scenario. For now it looks like this is the best approach

Okay. Thanks for your reply. Good luck!
